# Login Redirect PHP with Special Function

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have the following function set up in my includes and class file:

```
function makeMessage($message, $href, $onclick = '', $redirect = '', $linktext = 'Click here to continue') {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<strong>" . $message . "</strong><br><a href=\"" . $href . "\" onClick=\"" . $onclick . "\" class=\"button\">" . $linktext . "</a>";
    if (! empty ( $redirect ))
        echo "<br><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"" . $redirect . "\"><strong>You should be redirected within a few seconds...</strong>
                <br><br>Or let's <a href=\"delivery_info.php\">check out now!</a>";
    echo "</center>";
}
```

However, on my register and login, add to order all uses this function, but I'm unsure what broke. Here's how I'm using it:

```
if ($post ['price_id'] == 0) {
                                            $WALM->makeMessage ( 'You are now logged in!', 'order_now.php', '', 'order_now.php' );
                                        } else {

                                        }
```

The problem is, that it's not working with the meta refresh, does anyone have any help here to change this about and to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tags should be placed within the  section. Maybe it's the problem?
You could try a JS redirect as follow:

```
function makeMessage($message, $href, $onclick = '', $redirect = '', $linktext = 'Click here to continue') {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<strong>$message</strong><br/><a href=\"$href\" onClick=\"$onclick\" class=\"button\">$linktext</a>";
    if (!empty ($redirect))
        echo "<br>
              <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  window.location = \"$redirect\"
              </script>
              <strong>You should be redirected within a few seconds...</strong>
              <br><br>Or let's <a href=\"delivery_info.php\">check out now!</a>";
    echo "</center>";
}
```

### EDIT

You can not send headers considering that the redirect is not to the top of the page. If you want to delay the redirect, you can use the [setTimeout() JS function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @mRkZ94

Answer (score 0):

Use `header()` instead of `<meta>`

```
function makeMessage($message, $href, $onclick = '', $redirect = '', $linktext = 'Click here to continue') {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<strong>" . $message . "</strong><br><a href=\"" . $href . "\" onClick=\"" . $onclick . "\" class=\"button\">" . $linktext . "</a>";
    if (! empty ( $redirect )) {
        header("refresh:5;url=$redirect");
        echo "<br><strong>You should be redirected within a few seconds...</strong>
                <br><br>Or let's <a href=\"delivery_info.php\">check out now!</a>";
    }
    echo "</center>";
}
```